# Get text from object HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The DateFunction sets today's date in the text input with id `datelate`.
The date is then stored in the `date` variable in the `addLate` function as an `object HTMLInputElement`. Everytime I try to extract the date stored in the variable, it says: `[object HTMLInputElement]` instead of the actual date. How do I get only the actual date from the input?

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function DateFunction() {
    today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    document.getElementById('datelate').value= today;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addLate").click(function(){

          var fname=$("#firstname").val();
          var lname=$("#lastname").val();
          var date=$("#datelate").val();
          var time=$("#time").val();
          var detdate=$("#detentiondate").val();
          var reason=$("#reason").val();
        if (fname !== "" && lname !== "" && date !== "" && time !== "" && reason !== "") {
              $.ajax({
                  type:"post",
                  url:"late.php",
                  data:"firstname="+fname+"&lastname="+lname+"&date="+datelate+"&time="+time+"&detentiondate="+detdate+"&reason="+reason,
                  success:function(){
                     alert("Late note added");
                     window.location.href = "home.php";
                  }
              });
        } else {
                alert("You must fill out all the empty information!");
            }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datelate" readonly>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/vvLp8joj/

Comment: just change `datelate` by `date` in `&date="+datelate`

Comment: @wrxsti I am storing it into a mySQL database. When I do a SELECT query on the database, it returns with `objectHTMLInputElement` instead of the date.

Comment: @SamG That is because when you are storing it in the database you aren't storing the proper value. You are sending it the wrong variable initially. Check my answer you will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you didn't name the variable properly in your data set.

```
var date=$("#datelate").val();

data:"firstname="+fname+"&lastname="+lname+"&date="+datelate+"&time="+time+"&detentiondate="+detdate+"&reason="+reason
```

should be

```
data:"firstname="+fname+"&lastname="+lname+"&date="+date+"&time="+time+"&detentiondate="+detdate+"&reason="+reason
```

Notice the difference in the variable `date` and `datelate`

Comment: I understand! Thank you. I'm not so clear on the whole AJAX data sending. Have I also done the other variables incorrectly in the `data:`  line?

Comment: @SamG Don't forget to mark a correct answer, if we solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: How come the other variables have the id's they originated from next to them in the data set, but the `date`  variable doesn't? That's why I originally thought it should be `&date="+datelate`.

Comment: @SamG Its only the var date=$("#datelate").val(); that is important. If you were to change it to var datelate=$("#datelate").val(); then the original data set string would have worked.

Answer (score 4):

You append a variable:

```
"&date="+datelate+
```

that shares its name with the id of the element (so reflects the result of its `toString()`) as opposed to the correct variable you create here:

```
var date=$("#datelate").val();
```

Append `"&date="+date+`.

Comment: You have not defined the variable `datelate` you use to build your string, you declared a variable called `date` instead.  As `datelate` has not been defined by *you*, and because its also the id of an element, it defaults to *being*  that element.